# Cannot install HTF on osx with cabal

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, cabal-install, htf

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094319/trouble-installing-htf-with-cabal) regarding installing HTF and errors with `cpphs`, but it doesn't seem to apply. I did a 100% fresh haskell platform install on two seperate osx machines, and tried to do `cabal install htf --global` (after installing `cpphs` and adding it to the path), and I still get this error.  How do I get HTF to install?

```
Building HTF-0.11.0.1...
Preprocessing library HTF-0.11.0.1...
/var/folders/b4/m9gsxwt15s329sq82kc0h8yr0000gn/T/ghc15193_0/ghc15193_0.hscpp: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Failed to install HTF-0.11.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HTF-0.11.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

---

Output of `cabal install -v HTF`

```
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install HTF-0.11.0.1
Waiting for install task to finish...
Extracting
/Users/akropp/Library/Haskell/repo-cache/hackage.haskell.org/HTF/0.11.0.1/HTF-0.11.0.1.tar.gz
to /var/folders/b4/m9gsxwt15s329sq82kc0h8yr0000gn/T/HTF-0.11.0.1-15624...
Updating HTF.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
Configuring HTF-0.11.0.1...
Dependency Diff ==0.3.0: using Diff-0.3.0
Dependency HUnit ==1.2.5.2: using HUnit-1.2.5.2
Dependency QuickCheck ==2.6: using QuickCheck-2.6
Dependency aeson ==0.6.2.1: using aeson-0.6.2.1
Dependency array ==0.4.0.1: using array-0.4.0.1
Dependency base ==4.6.0.1: using base-4.6.0.1
Dependency bytestring ==0.10.0.2: using bytestring-0.10.0.2
Dependency containers ==0.5.0.0: using containers-0.5.0.0
Dependency cpphs ==1.17.1: using cpphs-1.17.1
Dependency directory ==1.2.0.1: using directory-1.2.0.1
Dependency haskell-src-exts ==1.14.0: using haskell-src-exts-1.14.0
Dependency lifted-base ==0.2.1.1: using lifted-base-0.2.1.1
Dependency monad-control ==0.3.2.2: using monad-control-0.3.2.2
Dependency mtl ==2.1.2: using mtl-2.1.2
Dependency old-time ==1.1.0.1: using old-time-1.1.0.1
Dependency pretty ==1.1.1.0: using pretty-1.1.1.0
Dependency process ==1.1.0.2: using process-1.1.0.2
Dependency random ==1.0.1.1: using random-1.0.1.1
Dependency regex-compat ==0.95.1: using regex-compat-0.95.1
Dependency text ==0.11.3.1: using text-0.11.3.1
Dependency unix ==2.6.0.1: using unix-2.6.0.1
Dependency xmlgen ==0.6.2.0: using xmlgen-0.6.2.0
Using Cabal-1.16.0 compiled by ghc-7.6
Using compiler: ghc-7.6.3
Using install prefix: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1
Binaries installed in: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1/bin
Libraries installed in: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1/lib
Private binaries installed in:
/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1/libexec
Data files installed in: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1/share
Documentation installed in: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/HTF-0.11.0.1/doc
Using alex version 3.0.5 found on system at: /usr/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
Using cpphs version 1.17.1 found on system at:
/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/cpphs-1.17.1/bin/cpphs
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.2.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.13.2 found on system at: /usr/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.18.10 found on system at: /usr/bin/happy
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
Using pkg-config version 0.25 found on system at: /usr/bin/pkg-config
Using ranlib found on system at: /usr/bin/ranlib
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /usr/bin/tar
No uhc found
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building HTF-0.11.0.1...
Preprocessing library HTF-0.11.0.1...
Building library...
creating dist/build
/usr/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name HTF-0.11.0.1 -hide-all-packages -no-user-package-db -package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id Diff-0.3.0-ae9a41c431459494fc7bc5c187ba33e6 -package-id HUnit-1.2.5.2-037d72e94f82e21ad0efc3a3ca13d5e2 -package-id QuickCheck-2.6-dda070bd88857faef781f77c1d409eb2 -package-id aeson-0.6.2.1-cbe09e156fefa8297b633622cffb7975 -package-id array-0.4.0.1-6380782b62ead58fec616aa07dc0e15c -package-id base-4.6.0.1-65ac4928fcfbf023405fccf5c07872a6 -package-id bytestring-0.10.0.2-5e74e527b574bd4fd17a67ce1aabc032 -package-id containers-0.5.0.0-3b8b869ec10d44736414ab5bea776319 -package-id directory-1.2.0.1-0f67c785af47905b06cf5ac249e605af -package-id haskell-src-exts-1.14.0-31ec1db95d69be28ab4e2ebf0a300533 -package-id lifted-base-0.2.1.1-6e5b30a6bf58234a7dcc563456b9fce1 -package-id monad-control-0.3.2.2-93d9fbfe359b316362ed369a29269fa9 -package-id mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee -package-id old-time-1.1.0.1-978f23f270668d2fce2ccde5417e64e6 -package-id pretty-1.1.1.0-2de27f83b2c1c65d629a564e9e01b27d -package-id process-1.1.0.2-89ae8237c033e0bc2595bd41c421d2b4 -package-id random-1.0.1.1-5f416fe0f1490f10e0732251731e138a -package-id regex-compat-0.95.1-01a41bc749209c56e2a50c83393b613f -package-id text-0.11.3.1-f49c096093e03f96dfcd6a84bb11661e -package-id unix-2.6.0.1-c862e7b569ef7e88fc8076e1e0f155b0 -package-id xmlgen-0.6.2.0-1326aa582fe0fb48c0d8bd3c7bae7e8c -XHaskell2010 Test.Framework Test.Framework.HUnitWrapper Test.Framework.TestManager Test.Framework.TestTypes Test.Framework.TestReporter Test.Framework.CmdlineOptions Test.Framework.QuickCheckWrapper Test.Framework.BlackBoxTest Test.Framework.Location Test.Framework.Tutorial Test.Framework.Pretty Test.Framework.JsonOutput Test.Framework.XmlOutput Test.Framework.ThreadPool Test.Framework.TestManagerInternal Test.Framework.Utils Test.Framework.Colors Test.Framework.Diff Test.Framework.Process -W -fwarn-unused-imports -fwarn-unused-binds -fwarn-unused-matches -fwarn-unused-do-bind -fwarn-wrong-do-bind
Failed to install HTF-0.11.0.1
World file is already up to date.
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `cabal install -v HTL`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, i've updated with the output. It didn't have `HTL` so I assume you meant `HTF`